# Error AssetNotFound - How to send XCM Instruction::Transact?

Tags: xcm, staking, astar, xcmv3

I have a couple of questions related to sending XCM messages. More specifically, I am trying to send a message from an Astar node to the Polkadot relay chain.

The XCM message contains the `Instruction::Transact` to target the [create nomination pool extrinsic](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/7c1dc9429245d705ffb188b16ad5339c6de281c1/runtime/polkadot/src/xcm_config.rs#L293C39-L293C39) ([parameters](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/dc3fb3d4cf9efb779a068cdc201babc7ae2d233c/frame/nomination-pools/src/lib.rs#L2236) of the extrinsic in paritech/substrate).

I am getting the following event in the Polkadot relay chain which contains the error **`AssetNotFound`**:
[image]

Does this error indicate that the target extrinsic itself was not found?

And it is not clear to me how Polkadot can use Alice's currency `BSPY` since the account is in Astar and is not using `DOT`. How can Polkadot create a nomination pool using Alice's `BSPY` funds?
[image]

I made sure as well that my type indexes matched the NominationPool pallet and create extrinsic [here](https://github.com/ok-Alice/Astar/blob/liquid-staking/pallets/nomination-pools-staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L45-L61).

**Here is the [XCM code](https://github.com/ok-Alice/Astar/blob/liquid-staking/pallets/nomination-pools-staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L219-L276) executed from Astar pallet extrinsic.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this by changing the `MultiAsset` location to point to the target chain I would be executed the operation on. In this case, the location should be the Polkadot relay chain (parent).

Changed from this:

```rust
calls.push(Instruction::WithdrawAsset((Here, 10_000_000u64).into()));
calls.push(Instruction::BuyExecution {
      fees: (Here, 10_000_000u64).into(),
      weight_limit: xcm::v3::WeightLimit::Unlimited,
});
```

to this:

```rust
let location: MultiLocation = MultiLocation {
    parents: 1,
    interior: Here,
};

calls.push(Instruction::WithdrawAsset((location, 10_000_000u64).into()));
calls.push(Instruction::BuyExecution {
      fees: (location, 10_000_000u64).into(),
      weight_limit: xcm::v3::WeightLimit::Unlimited,
});
```